# If an ant jumps from one vertex to another of a regular decagon, based on a condition, which vertex will he be on after his workout?

Tags: geometry, number-theory, complex-numbers, polygons

> **QUESTION:** Brilli the ant stands on vertex $1$ of a regular decagon..
>
> He starts by hopping $1$ space at a time (from $1$ to $2$, then from $2$ to $3$, and so on). He performs $10$ hops in this way.
>
> He then hops $2$ spaces at a time (from $1$ to $3$, then from $3$ to $5$, and so on). He performs $10$ hops in this way.
>
> He continues to increase the hop distance every $10$ hops: hopping $3$ spaces $10$ times, then hopping $4$ spaces $10$ times, and so on.
>
> After Brilli has hopped $10$ spaces $10$ times, he ends his workout.
>
> When Brilli has completed his workout, which vertex will he be standing on?

**MY ANSWER:** This is an easy problem. I have figured out a simple number theoretic approach to this one..
It's trivial to see that the first round brings the ant back to vertex $1$.
Then, he basically jumps $2 \times 10$ spaces. That results in vertex $20$, which is nothing but vertex $1$ $(\because 10 \mid 20 \text{ and every vertex is } \equiv 0 \pmod{10})$.
Then for the third round we get $30$ spaces, which brings him back to vertex $1$ again.
Continuing in this fashion, we get that eventually after the workout, Brilli will be back to where he started from, i.e. vertex $1$.

Now, my question is a bit different. Lets look at this same problem from the complex geometry side.. We know that the vertices are nothing but the $10^{\text{th}}$ roots of unity. Now, at an official solution, it was written that --

**Peforming the $10$ "hops" around the decagon is just like raising a $10^\text{th}$ root of unity to the $10^\text{th}$ power.**

I did not understand this statement... Why is that?
The ant is just hopping around from one root to another (that is to say, the vertices)... How does "raising the $10^{\text{th}}$ root (which is $1$) to the $10^{\text{th}}$ power help?"

Can anyone please clarify this geometry a bit clearly. Thank you so much..

Source: Brilliant.

Comment: If the ant jumps from vertex $n$ to vertex $n + k$, it's "multiplying its position with $\exp \frac{2\pi i k}{10}$".

Comment: There are $10$ tenth roots of unity, eight complex roots and $\pm1$.  The problem is no doubt referring to $\cos\frac{2\pi}{10}+i\sin\frac{2\pi}{10}$

Comment: @saulspatz Then why raise it to the $10^{\text{th}}$ power?

Comment: Look at Daniel Fisher's comment.

Answer (score 1):

$$\underbrace{ \left( e^{(2 \pi i)/10} \right)^{10}}_{=1} \underbrace{ \left( e^{2 (2 \pi i)/10} \right)^{10}}_{=1} \cdots \underbrace{ \left( e^{ 10 (2 \pi i)/10} \right)^{10}}_{=1} = 1$$

where the power is because you take $10$ steps of each size.

Comment: Thank You so much for your answer... But can you please tell me 'why' we raise every root to the $10^{\text{th}}$ power ?